# Under counter LED strip lighting

Tags: lighting

We have the traditional long bulb light fixtures under our cabinet.  I am looking to replace those with an LED system.  We have Phillips Hue lights in a couple of rooms in our house, so I am familiar with their products.  But we want LED lights that...

1. Hook into AC power
2. Can work off the existing on/off wall switches
3. Have an app to control their color and brightness
4. Full color spectrum

I don't think the Hue lights can work off an existing wall switch.  Can someone recommend another option that meets our criteria?

Answer (score 2):

You must recognize that these products are not MAGIC.  They have a variety of inherent limitations.  For instance, you want to retain the fixtures you already have and use smart bulbs. That requires compromising away some functionality you'd live to have.  You'd like to retain the switches you have now, and have those function. That will require more compromise.

It's not going to be "exactly what you want" unless you're willing to go ALL-IN and abandon many of your preconditions.

Based on your requirements, you're probably going to need a "smart home" hub that your smart bulbs talk to.  That type of coordination is what smart hubs are for.

The weakness in "smart bulbs" is they cannot summon power from the aether. They get power when they are switched on, and the rest of the time, they don't have power. You want to keep your existing switches, which cut power to the smart bulbs. That means when you turn the light on, the smart bulb will be in an indeterminate state until it connects to the network and talks to the smart hub. To change that you would need to power them 24x7, and possibly replace the switch with a smart switch which also talks to the network.

Generally trying to have *2 different methods of control* that don't talk to each other (i.e. switch *and* phone) is the road to perdition.